# I don't know my server's mysql admin password

Tags: mysql, passwords, admin, root, plesk

Hi I will repair my tables in ssh but it want mysql admin password.

Admin password different then my plesk admin or root password.

I did't change admin mysql password.

/usr/local/psa/bin/admin --show-password this password isn't work

I want to get password or change but I don't know it.

I'm using plesk if I change password direct at mysql.users probably I cant login plesk.Is it wrong?

Please help me how can get or change this password?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz6Mr.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string stored in /etc/psa/.psa.shadow as mysql user admin password.

For example, to upgrade mysql tables try this command:

```
# mysql_upgrade -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
```

> I'm using plesk if I change password direct at mysql.users probably I cant login plesk.

It's true.